# Can Entity Framework Core code migrations work reliably and practically against different database types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to clarify that this is the Core version Entity Framework that I'm working with.

I think I know the answer, but it's all based on assumptions from other ORMs I used years ago. My guess is the answer is something like "it depends based on the specific database(s) and the features used (keys, constraints, etc)".

Additionally, I want to clarify that I'm not asking if migrations can be generated from the model for different DBs. I know the answer is yes to that. I'm asking about a single set of already generated migrations.

Comment: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/providers/index.html

Comment: You're asking if the *internal* migrations table that EF generates when tables are created can be copied to a completely different database technology and work?  Definitely not.

Comment: When did I ask anything about "internal migrations table"? Are you referring to the migration history table?

Comment: that's part of the migration.  the other half is the *platform specific* code that checks the migration history table to decide if tables need to be modified.  The entire process is database specific.  The code to create and/or drop tables is also database specific.  Migrations can't be plucked out and targeted against a different database type.

Comment: platform specific meaning .net core, 4.5, etc? I'm confused by your comment. Let me rephrase: by migration, I'm talking about the `20160822034047_MyMigration.cs` and `20160822034047_MyMigration.designer.cs` files that are generated. Is the generated code in those files DB and provider specific?

Comment: those migration files have database language in them, or, at least, code that communicates with the specific provider that has the database code (i.e. T-SQL).

Comment: Ok, well if anyone wants to type me up a more formal answer then I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single set of migrations **can** be applied to different database types. The tooling doesn't help much (issue [#1825](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1825)), so you may need to hand-edit the migration files.

Yes, it does depend on what features the databases support, so the path of least resistance is to use the lowest common set of features available across the providers. You can use annotations and the `ActiveProvider` property to influence provider-specific configuration. For example:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        table: "Blogs",
        name: "Id",
        nullable: false)
        // Use AUTOINCREMENT on SQLite
        .Annotation("Autoincrement", true)
        // Use IDENTITY on SQL Server
        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

    if (ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer")
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateSequence("SomeSequence");
    }
}
```