# Ignore schema attribute for SQLite during migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a shared model that will be used to create both SqlServer and SQLite databases.  I added the Table attribute onto each one of my model classes and supplied a schema:

```
[Table("Sites", Schema = "Common")]
```

When I migrate the SQLite database using `context.Database.Migrate()`, I get a NotSupportedException error.  I know that SQLite doesn't support schemas, so I was wondering if there was an easy way to ignore the schema attribute during migrate?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111308/can-entity-framework-core-code-migrations-work-reliably-and-practically-against and try to avoid using attributes for schema-related configuration.

Comment: This is unexpected. In general, schema should be ignored on SQLite. I've filed issue [#6679](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6679).

Answer (score 1):

Set the schema in code rather than by attribute. That way you can use some method/config to determine the schema, for example:

```
public class MyContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         if(UsingSqlLite)
         {
             modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().ToTable("Sites");
         }
         else
         {
             modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().ToTable("Sites", "Common");
         }
    } 

    //snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same migration on both SQL Server and SQLite, you probably need to ignore the schema inside the migration.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    if (migrationBuilder.ActiveProvider == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite")
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Sites",
            ...);
    }
    else
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Sites",
            schema: "Common",
            ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the SQLite version to remove the schema and it migrates the database successfully.  I now get a problem when I perform a query it says 'no such table: Common.Sites'

Comment: The SQLite provider will ignore schemas in version 2.0.0 making multi-provider scenarios easier. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6679